# Angular *ngFor show more/show less button for each element

Tags: angular

I am trying to find a solution for adding a show more/show less button for each element on the list which is built using `*ngFor`. I have no problem with one element because in this case, I can create some boolean variable and show/hide text on click but how to handle multiple elements?

I used a custom pipe for truncating the text inside element but maybe there is another better way to do that.

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'ellipsis'
})
export class EllipsisPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(val, args) {
    if (args === undefined) {
      return val;
    }

    if (val.length > args) {
      return val.substring(0, args) + '...';
    } else {
      return val;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you describe, you can use boolean value for one element. This implies that you can solve the problem if you have a boolean value per item in the array.

You can extend the item holder object with a boolean value which can hold info about the show/hide button.

```
interface Holder<T> {
  T value;
  bool showHide;
}
let array: Holder<string>[] = [];
```